# reformat Timestamp from unix to iso

Tags: unix-timestamp, jq

I´ve got Json input data, where i need to reformat the timestamp from unix-time to ISO 8601 (to process the file afterwards).
I tried to do this by using: 
`<input.json jq .[2].timestamp |= jq todate >output.json` 
This is reformating the timestamp in the right way, but how do i get the reformated timestamp back into the original file? I aim to get the original file with all its information, but reformated timestamp.

It works as i would like to have it at https://jqplay.org/ , but not in the command-line.
I appreciate your help!

Sample Input:

```
[
{
"channelId": 9088,
"errorCode": 0,
"value": 0,
"timestamp": 1460258309
},
{
"channelId": 10087,
"errorCode": 0,
"value": 1000,
"timestamp": 1460258294
},
{
"channelId": 10086,
"errorCode": 0,
"value": 90,
"timestamp": 1460258294
},
{
"errorCode": 0,
"errorLine": ""
 }
]
```

Wanted Output:

```
[
{
"channelId": 9088,
"errorCode": 0,
"value": 0,
"timestamp": 2016-04-10T03:18:14Z
},
{
"channelId": 10087,
"errorCode": 0,
"value": 1000,
"timestamp": 2016-04-10T03:18:14Z
},
{
"channelId": 10086,
"errorCode": 0,
"value": 90,
"timestamp": 2016-04-10T03:18:14Z
},
{
"errorCode": 0,
"errorLine": ""
 }
]
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample input and its expected output? Also, you probably mean to do `jq '.[2].timestamp |= todate'`, that is, in single quotes and without the additional jq invocation.

Comment: Added input and expected output. If i skip the second 'jq' cmd gets me the the error that the command is either misspelled or could not be found. Is there a general solution for this problem? I´m always running into this problem, when i try to use '|'

Answer (score 2):

With your input:

```
 <input.json jq 'map(if .timestamp then .timestamp |= todate else . end)'
```

the output is:

```
[
  {
    "channelId": 9088,
    "errorCode": 0,
    "value": 0,
    "timestamp": "2016-04-10T03:18:29Z"
  },
  {
    "channelId": 10087,
    "errorCode": 0,
    "value": 1000,
    "timestamp": "2016-04-10T03:18:14Z"
  },
  {
    "channelId": 10086,
    "errorCode": 0,
    "value": 90,
    "timestamp": "2016-04-10T03:18:14Z"
  },
  {
    "errorCode": 0,
    "errorLine": ""
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want every occurrence of the "timestamp" converted (no matter where it occurs), then if your jq has `walk/1` you can use the filter illustrated by the following:

```
jq -n '[{timestamp: (24*60*60)}] | walk(if type == "object" and .timestamp then .timestamp |= todate else . end)'
[
  {
    "timestamp": "1970-01-02T00:00:00Z"
  }
]
```

If your jq does not have `walk/1`, then you can copy its definition from https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq

Comment: Sorry, but i don´t know how to add the defintion of walk, i´m just using a executable *.exe version of jq. I added a sample input/output to my question. Is there a way to solve the problem without adding walk?

Comment: To add [walk/1](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq#L284-L291) (or any function) you can just put it's definition before the rest of your filter, e.g. `jq -n 'def walk(f): . as $in | if type == "object" then reduce keys_unsorted[] as $key ( {}; . + { ($key):  ($in[$key] | walk(f)) } ) | f elif type == "array" then map( walk(f) ) | f else f end; [{timestamp: (24*60*60)}] | walk(if type == "object" and .timestamp then .timestamp |= todate else . end)'`.  Another way would be to put it in your `~/.jq` file.